# Prove $f_n(x) = n^2 x (1-x)^n$ does not converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x) = n^2 x (1-x)^n$. Prove that $ f_n \rightarrow0$ pointwise in [0,1] but  does not converges uniformly (using the definition).

**What I've done**

$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$

$f_n(0) = f_n(1)=0$, so we have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2x(1-x)^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} n^2xe^{n \ln(1-x)} =0$$

Since $ \ln(1-x)<0$ for $0<x<1$ we have that $f(x)=0$ and so

$ f_n \rightarrow0 $ in [0,1] pontwise.

But I don't know how to apply the deffinition to prove that $f_n(x)$ does not converges uniformly

My deffinition (uniform convergence): $\forall\epsilon>0, \exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please fix the formula for the function in title and in the question. (Are we raising $(1-n)$ or $(1-x)$ to the power...?!)

Comment: Edited, didn't notice that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f_n(x)$ is given by $n^2x(1-x)^n$ for $x\in J:=[0,1]$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|f_n-0\|_\infty
&=\max_{x\in J}|f_n(x)|
\\
&\ge f_n(1/n)
\\
&=n^2\frac 1n\underbrace{\left(1-\frac 1n\right)^n}_{\to 1/e}
\\
&\to \infty\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the sequence of functions $(f_n)$ does not converge uniformly (i.e. in the supremum = infinity norm) to the pointwise limit, the only chance of a limit. (It is not even bounded.)